# Where's this town that a cruise ship is passing, beside fjord in Norway?

Tags: identify-this, norway

1. This is from [r/ruralporn](https://redd.it/65jyk6). [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivJYkWDHecvj6CKpNzzWba6JSs8XURqv1wDRF33RgZ87V1lvYGtiU9WMbAadRqHPM5b5QCSMHBck_1fDosUkli-HwZdvaKBJOpt7PgyzvqVeV7lwjCT4uKW46DXeSk8PJmWsDC425_1fkj3KhxGkWHBaTURQS7y4IDNt4zudYn0mWc5kMUFO0v3dQaOoc1bR8sE-LVmJORistjKWGU2uQ2_12usC8562-V68WKwdBos35GUkuVewTJF3ah2NRPI-zy1JkbN2L-sPRXp4uvruJE_14bkZdmX9zD1eQvCpNIeTZEHk-uDvbyaHUdG14G08Y5nHGMCbTgb&hl=en-CA) turned up just one result, but it doesn't identify the location.
2. Was this photo taken at a physical location, looking  down at the town? Or was it taken remotely like by a drone?

[image]

Comment: There's rock/soil and vegetation close to the POV at the bottom left, so the drone-thing is rather unlikely.

Comment: Someone has turned the saturation to +11 on their camera...

Comment: I'd argue that being in the air is also a physical location 

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is **Norangsfjorden** which branches from [Hjørundfjorden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hj%C3%B8rundfjorden) to the East. The small village in the foreground is [**Urke**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urke,_M%C3%B8re_og_Romsdal). I assume the **pic was taken from or near the summit of Leknesnakken**, a mountain directly west of Urke. See [this pic from Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/Kn2MPP1p7fixRbEK7):

[image]

Here's [another pic, showing both Norangsfjorden (left) and Hjørundfjorden (right), with Urke](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Urke_fra_Saksa.jpg) in the lower left and the Leknesnakken in the lower center. Camera position is near the Slopes or the Summit of Saksa, a mountain northwest of Urke.

[image: Urke fra Saksa; from Wikimedia Commons by Bjoron / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)]

<sup>Source: Wikimedia Commons, by Bjoron / [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)</sup>

The mountain with the distinctive summit at the left is the [Slogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slogen).

Comment: Thanks! How did you locate this town? Or have you visited this before?

Comment: @ChggOtrkWell - no, i've never been there - i've located it by combining an image search and Google Maps. An image search pointed to Norway, naming different fjords. I've located it by searching for the **distinctive dock/pier** shown on your pic in the vicinity of Geieranger Fjord. That's a feature that looks quite unique on the one hand, but very likely discernable on sat images on the other hand (because of its size, shape and colour). Together with the remarkable salient on the opposite shore, this led to Norangsfjorden, allowing for an image search on Norangsfjorden to corroborate it.

Comment: Wow, @tohuwawohu, that is awesome!

Comment: Note the difficulty of getting a shot without a cruise ship in it...